# WPF Window routes clicks to the window behind when closing!

Tags: c#, wpf, mouseclick-event

```
    private void Window_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        App.Current.MainWindow.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
        Close();
    }
```

A *click/click event* is also send to any window behind...
Even this bugs...

```
    private void Window_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        App.Current.MainWindow.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
        Close();
    }
```

Comment: It's kind of unclear what you're asking. So the window closes and then another application's window get the event? Or another window of your application gets the event? You could try setting `e.Handled = true`

Comment: Tried. Same results. The click goes to whatever was behind the mouse after the window closes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MouseDoubleClick is a direct routed event, and as such even setting `e.Handled = true` will not affect subsequent events up the tree. The suggested method for handling a double-click is to handle `MouseLeftButtonDown`, and check for `ClickCount == 2`. You can then set `e.Handled = true`, which should prevent the event from bubbling.

Comment: Other Controls only have to test `e.Handled` if they subscribed with `handledEventsToo`, right? See [AddHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms598899.aspx) - I think this is the only way to get handled events.

Comment: The issue is that MouseDoubleClick is a direct event, though I confused myself on what that meant. Even if you set Handled to true for it, the system will continue to send the event to UIElements up the tree, with e.Handled == false. I've updated my answer.

Comment: The control underneath will still pick up the leaked event as a MouseLeftButtonUp.